# Mongoose - Array in Schema not working + Mongoose find/match element in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

## Issue one

For some reason, when I post to my API using Postman (x-www-form-urlencoded), the Array of strings I created in the Schema (see below under issue 2) aren't being separated when I post using Postman. Either i'm not correctly posting, or I haven't set up my Schema correctly.

However I have tried multiple different ways of doing both. I originally had [String] in the Schema, I tried setting the key in Postman to day[] etc. but nothing seemed to work. Any ideas?

## Issue Two

(which cannot be completed until I get to the bottom of issue one.)

I am trying to return all results that contain 'friday' in the 'days' Array in the Schema, but I have searched everywhere and can't find this.

So given the Schema:

```
var PeopleSchema = new Schema({
   name: {
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
   days: {type: [String]}
});
```

and this data:

```
{ 
     _id: 1,
     name: 'Brian Smith',
     days: [ 'friday', 'monday', 'tuesday' ],
     available: true,
},
{ 
     _id: 2,
     name: 'Fred Hill',
     days: [ 'friday', 'wednesday', 'saturday' ],
     available: true,
}
```

I would like to find/match all results with say, 'friday' in the days Array. How would I do this?

Thanks very much

Comment: Simply do `People.find({"days": "friday"}).exec(callback);`

Comment: Related to Issue 1. The arrays are no longer arrays. Use "application/json" and JSON encode your data before sending. Postman will send correct JSON.